# Provide Access-Control-Allow-Origin in a java webservice

Tags: java, ajax, web-services, cross-domain

I am exposing a SOAP webservice written in java . I would like to have simple javascript clients access my webservice. Inorder to allow cross domain access by them, i would like to send  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in my response header.This should be send when the client sends a GET request to receive my wsdl file and also when the client POST a SOAP request. I do not know how to send such a header from my webservice. The webservice class is given below.

```
    @WebService()
    public class ChatServer {

        /** This is a sample web service operation */
        @WebMethod(operationName="echoChat")
        public Message echoChat(Message message){
            String userid="Server";
            message.setUserid(userid);
            return message;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a [SoapHandler](http://blogs.oracle.com/sdimilla/entry/implementing_handlers_using_jaxws_2) and see the request type and url and set the response header.

**Also See**

- [writing-a-handler-in-jax-ws](http://www.java-tips.org/java-ee-tips/java-api-for-xml-web-services/writing-a-handler-in-jax-ws.html)